# mysql_fetch_assoc echo specific row value

Tags: php, get

I want get the results of mysql_fetch_assoc as an array then echo a specific value in that array. How do I do that? I tried

```
$d = array();
while($row_dates = mysql_fetch_array($date_result)){
$d[] = $row_dates;
}

echo $d[1];// this would be the result from the first row
echo $d[3];// this should be the result from the second row.
```

I'm just getting Array as a result.

Comment: MYSQL functions are deprecated now. So please upgrade your code with MYSQLi or PDO. It is recommended

Comment: @EdwinAlex MYSQL is not deprecated but `mysql_` functions are deprecated ;)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below code

```
$d = array();
while($row_dates = mysql_fetch_array($date_result)){
    $d[] = $row_dates['your_column_name'];
}
```

you just miss the `column_name` in your code, everything else in your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_fetch_array
```

> Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

now here

```
$d[] = $row_dates;
```

what you assigning to `$d[]` is array instead value (i think what you want)

to check what you getting use `var_dump()` to `var_dump($row_dates);`

and now what you

```
while($row_dates = mysql_fetch_array($date_result)){
    $d[] = $row_dates['your_column_name'];
}
```